# I cannot assign values to dynamic cstring and modfiy them

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic, c-strings

For a homework problem, I need to implement a cstring class and overload operators. However, I am having trouble initializing the char array. In the following code,

```
StringClass::StringClass()
{
    c = new char[10];
    c = "Default";
    stringlength = strlen(c);
}
```

```
#pragma once
#include <fstream>
class StringClass
{
private:
    char* c;
    int stringlength;
public:
    StringClass();
    ~StringClass();
    void print()const;
    StringClass(char*, int);
    StringClass(const StringClass*);
    StringClass& operator=(const StringClass*);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, StringClass*);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const StringClass*);
    StringClass& operator+(const StringClass*);
    char operator[](int);
};
```

For the line c = "Default";
I get an error const char* cannot be assigned to char*,but I did not set c to a const. If I change char*c to const char* c, I can set it equal to default in the constructor but then I cannot modify it further. Why is this?

EDIT: I can change the declaration to this and it works properly. Is this the correct way to do this?

```
c = new char[10]{ "Default" };
```

Full implementation file,

```
#include "StringClass.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

StringClass::StringClass()
{
    c = new char[10];
    c = "Default";
    stringlength = strlen(c);
}

StringClass::~StringClass()
{
    c = NULL;
    delete c;
}

void StringClass::print()const
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << c[i];

    std::cout<< std::endl;

    std::cout << stringlength;
}
StringClass::StringClass(const StringClass* p)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        c[i] = p->c[i];
    }
    stringlength = p->stringlength;
}

StringClass& StringClass::operator=(const StringClass* a)
{
    if (this == a)
        return *this;
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        c = &a->c[i];
        stringlength = a->stringlength;
    }
    return *this;
}

//std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, StringClass* a)
//{
    //in >> a->c >> a->stringlength;
    //return in;
//}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const StringClass* a)
{
    out << a->c << " " << a->stringlength << std::endl;
    return out;
}

StringClass& StringClass::operator+(const StringClass* a)
{
    StringClass temp;
    temp.c = c + *a->c;
    temp.stringlength = stringlength + a->stringlength;
    return temp;
}

char StringClass::operator[](int a)
{
    return c[a];
}
```

Comment: Your edit answers your question! In your first code snippet, the `c = "Default";` line *replaces the pointer* (or, erroneously attempts to) allocated in the pervious line with the address of the (constant) string literal.

Comment: `c = "Default";` ***reassigns*** the variable `c`, it no longer point to the memory you previously allocated. What you're doing is similar to `int a = 5; a = 10;` and then wonder why `a` isn't equal to `5` anymore.

Comment: Ahh okay, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
c = new char[10]{ "Hello" };
```

Comment: Please don't write answers in a way that makes them look like questions.
There are systems in place to check for Not An Answer (NAA) posts.
This answer was falsely picked up by one of them. Please consider editing it to look more like an answer. Remove the "Is this the correct way to do this?" part and ask it here in the comments.